# Python how to sort a dictionary by value in reverse order

Tags: python

I want to sort a dictionary by value in reverse order.
For example: [Red: 2, Blue: 45, Green: 100]
to print Green 100, Blue 45, Red 2

Thanks

Comment: You have neglected to include any actual question, and that's no python dictionary. Please rectify this.

Comment: You may find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: You could iterate through the dictionary from top to bottom.
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/dict.html the first green box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sorted function.

```
d = dict(red=2, blue=45, green=100)
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> a = {"Red": 2, "Blue": 45, "Green": 100}

>>> OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
OrderedDict([('Green', 100), ('Blue', 45), ('Red', 2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used the Python tag but the dictionary is not a valid Python Dictionary. This is the right structure:

```
{"Red": 2, "Blue": 45, "Green": 100}
```

So, if you want to print it here is another way:

```
mydic = {"Red": 2, "Blue": 45, "Green": 100}
for w in sorted(mydic, key=mydic.get, reverse=True):
  print w, mydic[w]
```